# Angular2 : Router and auxiliary routes

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I'm playing with Angular2 auxiliary routes and I can't figure something out.

Let say we have a basic mail app with some contacts too.

Basically, my HTML look like this :

```
<div>
  <a [routerLink]="['emails']">Emails</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['contacts']">Contacts</a>
  <a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {aux: ['auxiliary']}}]">Open an auxiliary route</a>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
```

So far, it's **nearly** fine.

- `/emails` is diplaying fine
- `/contacts` is diplaying fine
- `/emails(aux:auxiliary)` is diplaying fine **at loading**
- `/contacts(aux:auxiliary)` is diplaying fine **at loading**

When the auxiliary is in URL, it's ok the first time we reach it.
But then, if I click on `<a [routerLink]="['emails']">Emails</a>`, my aux outlet is not displayed anymore even tho the URL is still `http://localhost:4200/emails(aux:auxiliary)`.

So my question is, how can we change the primary URL, without changing auxiliary routes ? (if no auxiliary, just go to new URL, if auxiliary, go to URL + auxiliary).

I tried :

```
<a [routerLink]="['emails', {outlets: {aux: ['/']}}]">Emails</a>
<a [routerLink]="['contacts', {outlets: {aux: ['/']}}]">Contacts</a>
```

and also

```
<a [routerLink]="['emails', {outlets: {aux: ['./']}}]">Emails</a>
<a [routerLink]="['contacts', {outlets: {aux: ['./']}}]">Contacts</a>
```

But it's not working either.

Thanks for any help !

PS : If you do want to try it by yourself, my test is on Github :

```
git clone https://github.com/maxime1992/angular2-nrgx-demo.git
git checkout auxiliary-route
npm i
ng serve
```

And just look to the following url : 
http://localhost:4200/emails

**EDIT :**

Here's a GIF to demonstrate the problem :
[image]

Comment: did you get any success with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can take care of this scenario by using dummy route,

The reason behind using dummy route is when you switch from /emails(aux:auxiliary) to /emails Angular doesn't reload the component because primary path is same. so you need to forcefully reload the component.

```
<a (click)="changeRoute(url)">
```

Add one dummy route to your router:

```
{ path: 'dummy', component: dummyComponent }
```

**dummyComponent.ts**

```
//Dummy component for route changes

@Component({
    selector: 'dummy',
    template: ''
})
export class dummyComponent{}
```

Now inside your component add **changeRoute** function:

```
changeRoute => (url){
    self.router.navigateByUrl('/dummy', { skipLocationChange: true });
    setTimeout(()=>self.router.navigate(['emails',{outlets: {aux: null}}]));
}

// {outlets: {aux: null}} this will set your outlet to null and clean your url to /emails
// 'skipLocationChange' will avoid /dummy to go into history API
```

This will re render your component and rest all will be taken care by Angular.

Comment: It doesn't appear that `url` is used, and that this is hard-coded to go to `emails`.

Also, the original question is, "how can we change the primary URL, without changing auxiliary routes ? (if no auxiliary, just go to new URL, if auxiliary, go to URL + auxiliary)." It looks like you *are* changing aux route.